# Is it possible to dynamically add hundreds of buttons to a tkinter gui?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, optimization, multidimensional-array

My goal is to create a Tkinter GUI using Python that is basically a giant 2d grid of buttons. I've been able to do this successfully with limitations.

It looks like this so far:

[image]

And the code to produce that image is this:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk 

def main():
    root = Application()
    root.geometry("900x650")
    root.title("Search algorithm visualizer")
    root.setup()
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def setup(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid()

        # initialize variables
        self.rows = 20
        self.cols = 20
        self.grid = np.empty(shape=(self.rows, self.cols), dtype=object) # actual grid

        # start functions
        self.setupgrid()


def setupgrid(self):
    for i in range(self.rows):
        for j in range(self.cols):
            button = self.grid[i][j] = tk.Button(self.frame, height=1, width=2, text="")
            button.grid(row=i, column=j)
    

main()
```

As you might have noticed, the grid dimensions are dictated by the cols and rows variables which contain the values 20 and 20, which would dynamically produce 400 button objects. The problem I'm facing is if I make the cols and rows variables high values (100 and 100 for example, which would produce 10,000 button objects) the program will freeze. I want to be able to add a huge number of buttons.

My question boils down to this:

- is it possible?
- if so, how can I optimize the program to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to accommodate 100x100 buttons? Python is a slow language compared to others out there, doing big tasks with it is going to take some time, it will work, but it will take time to generate 10,000 buttons.

Comment: I plan to make them small. It's basically going to be a canvas you can draw on, but instead, it is buttons that change colors, so ideally they would be tiny and there would be many of them.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Canvas` instead?

Comment: better use canvas or real image on canvas.

Comment: I might have to use canvas to do this, but the reason I don't really want to is that the concept of creating a 2d grid of buttons is really simple and theoretically easy to do. If using a canvas is the only way to do it, then it is what it is and I'll do it.